# Kotlin convert String to Iterable

Tags: kotlin

I have an iterable of `People` that I save as a `string` after converting from json. I want to know how would I convert the `string` back to a list.

```
// Save data
val peopleString = myList.toString()

// String saved is
[People(name=john, age=23), People(name=mary, age=21), People(name=george, age=11)]
```

Now is it possible to convert `peopleString` back to a list?

```
val peopleList: List<People> = peopleString.?
```

Comment: That string is not json (https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ proves it)

Comment: This feels like an XY problem, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can't deserialize an `Iterable<T>` since it's possibly an infinite list and `toString()` is **pretty print** instead of **serialize**.

Comment: Why don't you keep the original JSON string instead of `toString`'s output? Or at least use the same JSON infrastructure you already have to create a JSON string instead of `toString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no... kind of.

Your output is *not* JSON, and `toString()` is the wrong function to use if you wanted JSON. The output of `toString()` is not a proper serialization format that can be understood and used to rebuild the original data structure.

Converting a data structure into some format so that it can be transmitted and later rebuilt is known as [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). Kotlin has a serializer which can serialize objects into a number of different formats, including JSON: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#quick-example.

It's not as easy to use as `toString()`, but that's to be expected as `toStrings`'s purpose is very different from serialization.